# Php While in while

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

My first `while` is working very good. Second `while` works, but it isn't returning mysql records and I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$zapytanie_widget = "SELECT * FROM widgets";
$zapytanie_widget_sql = mysql_query($zapytanie_widget);
while($zapytanie_widget_row = mysql_fetch_row($zapytanie_widget_sql))
{
    $widget_query = "SELECT * FROM instaledwidgets";
    $widget_sql = mysql_query($widget_query);

    // THIS WHILE
    while ($widget_after = mysql_fetch_row($widget_sql));
    {
        $widgetname = $widget_after[1];
    }

    $z_widget_count = mysql_num_rows($widget_sql);
    echo $z_widget_count;

    if($z_widget_count == 1)
    {   
        echo '<div class="widget" id="'.$widgetname.'_widget">
              <h4 class="widget-title">'.$widgetname.'</h4>
              <div class="widget-content">';
        include 'funkcje/widgets/'.$widgetname.'/'.$widgetname.'.php';
        echo '</div>
              </div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="widget" id="status">
              <h4 class="widget-title">Serwery1</h4>
              <div class="widget-content">
              </div>
              </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: I would definitely attempt to reformat this into a single query joining widgets and installedwidgets.

Comment: Your loop just overwrites `$widgetname` on every iteration. If that query can only ever return a single result, why areyou using a loop to fetch it? And since the query string doesn't change every, you're wastefully running the same query over and over and over again.

Answer (score 10):

You must remove the semicolon here:

```
 while ($widget_after = mysql_fetch_row($widget_sql));
```

For more info about `while` syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 0):

remove ; at the end of second while; its make empty loop

Answer (score 0):

// THIS WHILE

```
while ($widget_after = mysql_fetch_row($widget_sql));  <---- this its the problem
{
    $widgetname = $widget_after[1];
}
```